# What does this linux ls command mean

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
ls -d */
```

What does this `*/` mean? What is this star in `ls` command? Is this same as `./`?

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a glob pattern it is used to match everything in the current directory. (files and directories).

`/` is used to match only directories (since they end with this character)

`-d` tells `ls` to just look for directories and not their contents.

So `ls -d */` will match all the directories in the current directory.

Comment: / is used to match only directories (since they end with this character)   What do you mean with this sentence ? directory name do not end like this.

Comment: if you turn around the command. Is it still the same. for example ls -d  /*

Comment: I mean directories are represented with a `/` at the end. If you turn around the command you won't have the same result. `/` is the root folder so `/*` will match everything at the root of your system.